# Make jumbotron background-image and text responsive

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `jumbotron` that adjusts its banner image to the whole screen.

When I tried to put text on top of the image, the text won't show up on mobile screens, because the image fits the mobile screen (it's becoming smaller in height).

**How can I adjust both my image and text to fit on any screen?**

```css
.widewrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
.widewrapper > img {
  width: 100%;
}
.post-content {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.thumbnail {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Original code -->
<div class="widewrapper thumbnail">
  <img class="" src="http://orig10.deviantart.net/f6bf/f/2007/054/1/9/website_banner_landscape_by_kandiart.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="post-content">
    <h2 class="text-white">ABOUT</h2>
    <h3 class="text-white">We invite you to enjoy a luxurious ground transportation service provided by our team of experts. We have the experience and skills to meet the expectations of every passenger and add value to every ride.</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add [media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to adjust the font size according to the size of the viewport. It works well but is time consuming.

An example below (you would need to adjust the values to your needs):

```
@media(max-width: 1580px) {
post-content {
font-size: 18px;
}

@media(max-width: 980px) {
post-content {
font-size: 16px;
}

@media(max-width: 700px) {
post-content {
font-size: 14px;
}
```

Some tools can also do this automatically for you, i use [this one](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/) but there are many others.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the image from your HTML and set it as background in CSS.

You could use:

```
background-image: url('');
background-size: cover;
```

```css
body, h2, h3 {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}

#background-wrapper {
  background-image: url('http://orig10.deviantart.net/f6bf/f/2007/054/1/9/website_banner_landscape_by_kandiart.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="background-wrapper">
  <h2>About:</h2>
  <h3>We invite you to enjoy a luxurious ground transportation service provided by our team of experts. We have the experience and skills to meet the expectations of every passenger and add value to every ride.</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this could be to use the [viewport-relative units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) for your font-size.

> `1 vw` unit is equal to `1%` of the the width of the initial
>   containing block.

***For example:***

```css
.widewrapper { width: 100%; }
.widewrapper > img { width: 100%; }
.post-content {
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
.thumbnail { position: relative; }
h2, h3 { color: #fff !important; margin: 8px; }
h3 { font-size: 2.3vw !important; color: #fff !important; }
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="widewrapper thumbnail">
  <img class="" src="http://orig10.deviantart.net/f6bf/f/2007/054/1/9/website_banner_landscape_by_kandiart.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="post-content">
    <h2 class="text-white">ABOUT</h2>
    <h3 class="text-white">We invite you to enjoy a luxurious ground transportation service provided by our team of experts. We have the experience and skills to meet the expectations of every passenger and add value to every ride.</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```